# Switch with NSData or Data Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, byte

I have a value stored in an Data type. When printed with:
 `debugPrint("/(batteryLevel as NSData)"` I get the following: `<05>` I'd like to create a switch with this result.

```
`let testBatteryStatus:NSData = BluejayManager.shared.batteryStatus as! NSData
                switch testBatteryStatus {
                case <05> : print("print")
                default: print("nope")
                }`
```

but it trows an error. "<" is unvalid. 
So when the value is <05> it's charging, when <04> critical, ect. Any guidance would be appriciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In switch statements in Swift you can use Strings, Ints, Tuples, as well as do neat things like value bindings and use where statements. AFAIK, there is no literal NSData type like you attempted to write with `<05>`. That's what is throwing the error.

Also, you printed the NSData. This "stringifies" the NSData to a printable format, which is why you think you can match on this in the switch statement.

My suggestion is to convert the NSData to a String or an Int (your case seems to be better suited to an Int), and match on that.

e.g.

```
var batteryInt: Int = 0
let batteryData:NSData = BluejayManager.shared.batteryStatus as! NSData
batteryData.getBytes(&batteryInt, length: MemoryLayout<Int>.size)
switch batteryInt {
    case 5 : print("yes!")
    default: print("nope!")
}
```